# AssertionError: No examples were yielded

Tags: python, tensorflow, audio

I'm trying to load audio data to classify audio data into speech and music based on gtzan_music_speech data but i'm getting this error:

`AssertionError: No examples were yielded.`

Code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Conv2D, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, MaxPool2D, Flatten, Dropout, Dense
from IPython.display import Audio
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
dataset =  tfds.load("gtzan_music_speech")
```

Comment: Please upgrade to the lastest `tfds` package and let us know?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to print your path in _generate_examples(self, path) function to check whether your image path is correct for the coding to get your images and labels so that it can generate examples successfully.